# How can I block my app from being available for sharing via Bluetooth?

Tags: android, permissions, bluetooth, sharing

How can I ensure that my Android application is not shareable via Bluetooth?

Using applications which allow users to share files, apps, etc., via Bluetooth (ie, free Bluetooth File Transfer from the Android Market), I have successfully transferred my application from one phone to another.

I've looked into forbidding Bluetooth transfer using Android's permissions, but nothing came even close.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a precondition - the app is not suppose to be shareable. Besides, I wrote "cannot", not "isn't".

Comment: You mean: You want your app not to be shared, yet technically, it can be shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, on non-rooted Android phones all apps **can't** be shared to other devices, unless some app doesn't implemet this functionality. On the other hand, if phone is rooted, there is no easy way to prevent `.apk` file from beeing copied to another device.

So, I think you shouldn't bother about this.

Comment: You are mistaken.  The apk files are not protected against reading, even on secured phones.  What you cannot do is *browse* the location where the apk files are stored, but the files themselves are readable.